# Google Scripts: Pull Google Document Based on User ID / Email

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Good Morning Stack!

I was looking for some advice for some expanded functionality on a Google Script that helps me track and process absence requests. The process is as follows:

1. A  user submits their form responses
2. The form responses are stored on a spreadsheet
3. A google doc, pre-created, is pulled and the values from the spreadsheet are implanted in the document.
4. The document is converted to a PDF
5. That PDF is automatically emailed to me.

However, some work policies have changed and I now need this form to have a signature that is unique to the person filling the form. In the past we simply printed the resulting PDF and had the person sign off on it.

I know I do not have the technicality to add on any sort of Electronic Signature functionality, nor is emailing that PDF to them an option as it doesn't create a fillable PDF (and my users don't really know how to digitally sign items anyways)

So what I was thinking is to create a form unique to each of the 15-20 users of this process and instead of a getFileByID, have the script check the Google Users account / email and pull the file created for them and stored in my drive instead.

As follows is my current, functional, script. How could I make this work?

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {


var Last_Name = e.values[2];
var First_Name = e.values[3];
var Middle_Initial = e.values[4];
var Work_Location = e.values[5];
var Job_Title = e.values[6];
var Contact_Number = e.values[7];
var Start = e.values[8];
var End = e.values[9];
var Time = e.values[10];
var Reason = e.values[11];
var D = new Date(); 

var copyId = DriveApp
.getFileById("1sdfjlsdf55asdfnk565enasdfnsnsd2")
.makeCopy("AbsenceRequest" + Last_Name + Start).getId();

var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId)

var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

copyBody.replaceText('keyLastName', Last_Name);
copyBody.replaceText('keyFirstName', First_Name);
copyBody.replaceText('keyMiddleInitial', Middle_Initial);
copyBody.replaceText('keyWorkLocation', Work_Location);
copyBody.replaceText('keyJobTitle', Job_Title);
copyBody.replaceText('keyContactNumber',Contact_Number);
copyBody.replaceText('keyStart', Start);
copyBody.replaceText('keyEnd', End);
copyBody.replaceText('keyTime', Time);
copyBody.replaceText('keyDate', D);  

copyDoc.saveAndClose();

var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

var Email = "email@email.org" + "," + "email@email.org";
var Subject = "Absence Request" 
var Body = "This is an absence request"
MailApp.sendEmail(Email, Subject, Body, {attachments: pdf});

DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```